При запуске Windows Forms (.NET) C# приложений компоненты передвигаются
Есть приложений на Windows Form на C#, основное окно Form1 и два UserControl
Form1:

US_Task:

И вот в US_Task я компоненты расставил так, а при запуске ComboBox сдвинулся и вообще как будто четкость пропала. Из-за чего это?
ЗАПУСК ПРОГРАММЫ


Никуда он не сдвинулся, это высота серой панели поменялась. А чтобы чёткочть была на экранах высокого разрешения, нужно поддержку dpi включать или использовать свежий .NET.

Очень зря вы WPF бросили, очень зря. Подход WinForms уже давно устарел и уже давно не используется. Все новые типы проектов (Xamarin, UWP, MAUI, WinUi и др.) используют XAML. Также сейчас многие используют WEB для разработки UI интерфейсов, а там HTML, который очень похож на XAML. Другими словами, вы сейчас намеренно взяли старую технологию в надежде, что там проще, хотя могли понять WPF и благодаря ему влиться в современную разработку UI )

@EvgeniyZ Winforms, если в нём как следует разобраться, тоже позволяет весьма неплохой и адаптивный UI клепать, я это понял уже после того как на WPF пересел. Смысл не в том, что Winforms какой-то не такой, а в том что в WPF UI делать в разы проще и свистоперделок там из коробки очень сильно больше, не говоря уж о MAUI, Windows App SDK и прочих новинках. Проблема Winforms не в том что он старый, поддерживается он хорошо сейчас, а в том что он бессмысленный, так как сейчас существует намного больше всего вкусного. Кстати, WinAppSDK 1.5 таки смогли в однофайл без установки SDK на машине клиента.

@aepot А я и не говорю, что WinForms не такой и на нем не сделать хорошо. Я говорю, что сейчас в .NET используется везде подход WPF с его XAML, но не подход WinForms. Человек вот (судя по вопросам), пересел с WPF на WinForms, что мне кажется, является плохим решением, о чем я и сказал.

Перестаньте предлагать WPF! Он устарел и умер. Если уж предлагаете что-то XAML-подобное, то только кроссплатформенный MAUI. ЗЫ: WinForms будут живы, пока живёт WinAPI. Т. е. вечно. ЗЗЫ: я не агитирую за винформы.

@EvgeniyZ Мне Я просто хочу разное пробовать, я кончено понимаю что WPF более современее. Я делаю одно и то же приложение на разным фреймворках для опыта т.к новичок. Просто пробую разные вариации.

@aepot А почему  высота серой панели поменялась? Тогда как мне ставить компоненты что бы они ровно вставлялилсь ?

@AlexanderPetrov Вникните в происходящее, а потом делайте выводы. Касательно "Умер" - бред, лучше WPF все еще нет ничего для чистой десктоп разработки, он до сих пор развивается и улучшается. Или вы предлагаете тащит бесполезный кросплатфрм сырого MAUI, ради чисто виндовского приложения? Ну ну... Или может вы предлагаете WinUI? Тот, который все еще по швам трещит от простых вещей? Все зависит от задачи, многие из которых WPF до сих пор отлично выполняет. Так что, не говорите ерунду, да и тут не предлагал кто либо WPF, перечитайте еще раз мои комментарии и поймите в чем был посыл.

Почему поменялась - вам виднее, вы же настраивали интерфейс. Откройте код дизайнера формы, проверяйте, как там оно прописано.

@AlexanderPetrov Хах, любопытно получилось. Буквально через два дня после наших комментариев, Microsoft обновляет WPF, а также рекомендует именно его и WinUI3 для разработки приложений под десктоп, а также говорит, что будет и дальше вкладывать в него средства. Так что вы очень сильно поспешили с выводами о его смерти )
